# Function that takes a hex-color and returns a named vector with the values of the RGB and possibly alpha channels

Tags: r, regex, hex, rgb

For example, the function should work like this:

```
# colors with no transparency
hex_values("#435690")

## red  green  blue
## "43" "56"   "90"
```

If the provided hex-color has an alpha channel, then the function should work like this:

```
# colors with transparency
hex_values("#435690FF")

## red  green  blue  alpha
## "43" "56"   "90"  "FF"
```

I'm doing this with regex and for loops to write my function, but still running into many issues.

Any advice/help is appreciated!

Comment: have you checked th `gplots` package? especialy the `col2hex` function, that gets you part way there

Comment: Thank you both for your help! Yes, I forgot to add the # symbol before the hex colors in my question above. Just changed it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `col2rgb()` and transpose the result:

```
t(col2rgb("#435690FF", alpha = TRUE))

     red green blue alpha
[1,]  67    86  144   255
```

Or as r2evans pointed out, to revert to hex values wrap it in `as.hexmode()`.

```
t(as.hexmode(col2rgb("#435690FF", alpha = TRUE)))

     red  green blue alpha
[1,] "43" "56"  "90" "ff"
```

To incorporate the comments and wrap it all into a function:

```
hex_values <- function(x) {
  clr <- ifelse(startsWith(x, "#"), x, paste0("#", x))
  t(toupper(as.hexmode(col2rgb(clr, alpha = TRUE))))
}

hex_values(colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"))(5))

     red  green blue alpha
[1,] "FF" "00"  "00" "FF" 
[2,] "BF" "00"  "3F" "FF" 
[3,] "7F" "00"  "7F" "FF" 
[4,] "3F" "00"  "BF" "FF" 
[5,] "00" "00"  "FF" "FF"
```

Comment: If the OP really does want the output in hex, wrap this with `as.hexmode(...)`.

Comment: @r2evans - thanks, I didn't look closely enough at OP's expected output.

Comment: Thank you both again for your help! Is there any way to make the output code for alpha show up as "FF" instead of "ff"?

Comment: @Taylor - there's inbuilt error checking in `col2rgb()` - it will error with "invalid RGB specification" for invalid values. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: No, the channels are specified by pair position - (R = 00-FF, G = 00-FF, B = 00-FF, A = 00-FF).